# Tensorflow - How to create a neural network of variable size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm attempting to write a Python program that basically loops through many possibilities of Tensorflow neural networks. In other words, I want to make a loop that trains an algorithm with one hidden layer, and then tries two hidden layers, etc. However, I can't seem to find any documentation that points me in the right direction, and wanted to check and see what the consensus is on how to approach this.

Thank you!

EDIT: Using the comments and answers below, I took a closer look at some documentation -- [particularly this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough#select_the_model) -- and intend on using a for loop within each session to append layers to a Sequential model.

I'll provide an update on how this works when I get time to implement it.

Comment: Why don't you try creating a new model at each iteration while adding/deleting a layer and after prediction delete it and make a new one at next iteration?

Comment: @AnkishBansal This is my general idea, but I can't find anything in the TensorFlow/Keras documentation that allows me to build a model in this incremental way. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Once nodes are added to a TensorFlow session graph, they are not meant to be removed. Instead, the [session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#close) can be closed after each neural network is trained and a new session opened. This will free resources and create a new graph for each network.

```py
#Create neural network 1
with tf.session() as sess1: #"sess1" for clarity. Call all sessions "sess" in practice
    #Create your first network and perform training operations like usual
    #...

    #Close the session, freeing all resources
    sess1.close()

#Create neural network 2
with tf.session() as sess2: #"sess2" for clarity. Call all sessions "sess" in practice
    #Create your second network and perform training operations like usual
    #...

    #Close the session, freeing all resources
    sess2.close()
```

You can repeat the process as many times as you like. Each neural network can be saved from within each session (to different files).

Comment: This is a great start! I suppose more specifically my question is how can I create a loop that does the minutiae of writing out each network by hand for me? I was imagining some sort of for loop implementation that allows me to make these sessions repeatedly.

Comment: You could create and close the sessions inside the loop. For each network, create a session, call a function to create the network, train and save, then close the session. Repeat until all your networks are iterated over.